# SQLite classpath issue

Tags: java, sqlite, classpath

Given

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>sqlitejdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqlitejdbc</artifactId>
        <version>0.5.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

When running my tests, some fail with

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sqlite.JDBC
```

pointing to line that

```
    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + "some_name.db");
```

The error appeared out of nowhere. What could I be missing please?

Comment: Are you using mvnrepository as your Maven Repository? I can't find a SQLite version 0.5.6.

Comment: Using work's own repo

Comment: Is the jar there? Check if it's being downloaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry everyone this issue is my fault. Here is why i let this happen (listing in case someone else falls into the same trap)

I did this

```
    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");

    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + "unique");
    prep = con.prepareStatement(ANOTHER_SQL);

    Statement statement = con.createStatement();
    statement.executeUpdate("some sql");

    con.setAutoCommit(false);
```

instead of this

```
    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");

    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + "unique");

    Statement statement = con.createStatement();
    statement.executeUpdate("some sql");

    con.setAutoCommit(false);

    prep = con.prepareStatement(ANOTHER_SQL);
```

Thanks everyone for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to your pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```